# what do StorageRead and StorageWrite represent

Tags: azure-monitoring, azure-storage-files

I am trying to understand what properties Azure monitoring are recording for a storage account/file share. One of the property is `Category`, the explanation here does not make sense to me.

From this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-monitoring?tabs=azure-portal#collection-and-routing

```
Category              Description
StorageRead     Read operations on objects.
StorageWrite    Write operations on objects.
StorageDelete   Delete operations on objects.
```

What does `objects` represent here? Can it be a file from Azure file sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Objects` represent `File Shares`, `Directories` and `Files` in context of File Storage.

**UPDATE**

So I configured one of my storage accounts for logging and specified that the logs be stored in another storage account (don't have a log analytics workspace in my subscription that I could have used).

[image]

After that I performed following operations:

- **Shares**: Create, list, delete
- **Directory**: Create, list, delete
- **File**: Create, list, delete

I noticed that 3 blob containers were created in the storage account I specified during configuration:

[image]

These blob containers contained some JSON files that have the logs of the operations I performed. It took a few minutes for the initial blob container creation and then there was a few minutes delay in getting the data in the blob containers after an operation has been performed.

Comment: Still a bit confused. Take Azure file for example, does `objects` here represent a specific file created inside a File share folder/path?

Comment: In other words, does `StorageDelete ` mean a deletion of a specific file?

Comment: It could definitely mean a specific file but then it is not restricted to just file. So if you delete a file share, that is also considered part of `StorageDelete` operation.

Comment: Hmm. that is inconsistent with what I observed. I deleted a file in Azure file folder and tried to query `AzureActivity` table under `Logs(preview)`. But nothing returned.

Comment: That works only for `Archive to a storage account`.  It is not working if you `Stream to an event hub`. But I guess I will ask that in a separate question. Thanks.